# Two-part Bootstrap navigation menu with logo in the center

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I am making a dynamic wordpress links in navigation bar using nav_walker. How can i implement center something like this in wordpress nav_walker:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------------------------+
+---------------HOME--ABOUT---|-LOGO HERE-|---CONTACT--PROFILE-----------+
+-----------------------------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

How can i do that or something provide me jsfiddle to come up with that please.
Is it two nav_walker function for left and right navigation? how can i insert the navbar brand in center? can anyone give me structure. thanks.

my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-brand navbar-center">

    </div>

    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'menu'           => 'primary-1',
        'theme_location' => 'primary-1',
        'depth'          => 2,
        'container'      => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
        )); 
    ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa yes sir. i tried two divs but it fails. i made it two navigations. it doesn't come up for what i've want. :( please help me sir. thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking on how to get Menu Items from you're wordpress menu and divide them. Take a look at [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)

Comment: i already have the menu sir.. i only need is to divide them like what i posted. the alignment that could automaticaly divide them into two with the logo in center

Comment: "wp_nav_menu" display the full menu. However "wp_get_nav_menu_items" gives you the actual items from the menu. You can get the length of the array that is returned and divide it in half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can by suprisingly simple if you have same amount of items on left and on right. Just create a list, put the logo in the middle and do `text-align: center`. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26132/

The trouble starts when the left and right are even slightly uneven. I suggest creating two lists, each for half of the screen. They will be aligned towards the center and leave a space in the center for the logo.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26133/

html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <div class="logo"><img class="logo" src="http://www.hsdtaxlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logo_placeholder.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">      
        <ul class="left-navlist">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="half">      
        <ul class="right-navlist">
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Profile</li>
            <li>Maps</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.logo-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: -37px;
}

.logo {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
}

.half {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.right-navlist {
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.left-navlist {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
}
```

As for how to implement this with wordpress, I believe you will have to get rid of the navwalker plugin. Just create two menus in wordpress: `left-primary` and `right-primary`. Then just iterate them with `wp_get_nav_menu_items('left-primary')` and build the menu as I suggested. Here is the php code without the nav-walker:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <div class="logo"><img class="logo" src="http://www.hsdtaxlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logo_placeholder.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">      
        <ul class="left-navlist">
            <?
                $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('left-primary');
                foreach ($menu as $menu_item) {
                    $title = $menu_item->title;
                    $link = $menu_item->url;
                    ?>
                        <li href="<?=$link?>"><?=$title?></li>
                    <?
                ?
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="half">      
        <ul class="right-navlist">
            <?
                $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('right-primary');
                foreach ($menu as $menu_item) {
                    $title = $menu_item->title;
                    $link = $menu_item->url;
                    ?>
                        <li href="<?=$link?>"><?=$title?></li>
                    <?
                ?
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer sir. i edited my post and somehow.. i want to know how to divide my navwalker because i am using a wordpress.

Comment: I feel that this should be accepted as the answer as it does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @JcJohn I added the php code without the navwalker. All you need to do is add two menus in wordpress: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/

Comment: @JcJohn Always happy to help. You might also have just one menu and put even items to the left and odd to the right.

Comment: This solutions breaks the responsiveness of the menu. Why cant you just call the nav walker for each menu. Can you explain the point of getting rid of the nav walker please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok try using the below markup to achieve what you are looking for, you also need to tweak a little of CSS to override the bootstrap's default styles.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <a class="navbar-brand">Your logo</a>
         <li><a href="../navbar/">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="../navbar/">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

The **CSS** which achieves what you want(make sure this overrides the default bootstrap styles)

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 40%; //adjust to your requirements
}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/LRmxrA)

Comment: how can i divide the navwalker into split two sir.. thanks for your answer

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by splitting into two ? [Check this codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/LRmxrA) please.

Comment: i mean the dynamic navwalker wordpress function sir which makes the navigation dynamic adding pages. how can i make it automatically divide into two and in the center of them is the logo sir

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I was looking for the exact same thing and came across this pen. 
props to [Bryan Willis](https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/)

[Bootstrap 3 Headers](https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq) Look at last example !

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar9">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="brand-centered">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img style="margin-right: 10px; padding: 0;" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/disputebills/image/upload/v1462474206/blue-mark_cnzgry.png" alt="Dispute Bills">Dispute Bills
  </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar9" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid -->
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
/* EXAMPLE 9 - Center with Flexbox and Text*/
.brand-centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.brand-centered .navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```