# Centered Logo in Navigation Bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

can anybody guide me to the best way to create a navigation bar with a centered logo and 2 links in each side just like this:

[image]

Ive read about different ways like splitting a ul into 2 and floating one left and the other right and then centering the logo but im not sure how to do that and the more I read the more I got confused.
I am looking for it to be responsive and for it to be taller than normal, maybe 15/20% of the screen height.

Can anybody help me on how to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two-part Bootstrap navigation menu with logo in the center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973691/two-part-bootstrap-navigation-menu-with-logo-in-the-center)

Comment: Could you fix the image link?

Comment: @Crowes can you see it now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use Flexbox. Just replace the div #logo with your image.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Artwork</a>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <a href="">Responses</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}

#logo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">Artwork</a>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <a href="">Responses</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes! this works a charm, thanks a lot. Although I am have issues making my logo a link to index.html, it nudges off center when I do so but I can worry about that later. I'm actually using flexbox to create a 4 column grid for a poftfolio of images but I'm getting a margin at the top or bottom of each row, do you know whats going on here? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoawLB

Comment: You're welcome, sry for the late reply. Glad could have helped. If you still have the issue with the logo feel free to post a fiddle so I can have a short look at it if you want. Yeah the problem is that your images probably have a different height. Flexbox won't align it like a masonry gallery. If you want something like this you can have a look at this [pen](http://codepen.io/svelts/pen/ogboNV) I've made earlier. You can also add align-items: center to your flex container but I don't know if this is your desired effect.

Comment: Unfortunately not a usable solution.The logo is only centered if the links either side happen to be exactly the same size...

Comment: Agree with @00-BBB, in my case the left and right menu is not balance, and the logo won't be centered.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer breaks if the links aren't EXACTLY the same size (not likely in the real world, obviously could set a fixed width but fiddly)

If there are the same number of links on either side, this works (*as long as there is enough room either side for the links to have an even width*)

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navi-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.navi-list li:not(.centered-logo) {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navi">
    <ul class="navi-list">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="centered-logo">
          <a href="/">
             <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If an uneven number, you can add empty invisible elements (yuk I know but it works) either in the DOM or with :before / :after, depending on how many extra elements are needed.  This solution is unfortunately not perfect so any suggested improvements would be great.
Like this:

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navi-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.navi-list li:not(.centered-logo) {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navi-list:before {
  content: "0";
  opacity: 0.1;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 auto;

  
  /*  dev view  */
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo {
   background: grey;
   color: white;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navi">
    <ul class="navi-list">
<!--         <li style="opacity:0.1;">empty</li> -->
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="centered-logo">
          <a href="/">
             <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex: 1` on your link sections to keep the logo centered :

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-left, .nav-right {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Artwork</a>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-center">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/140x50?text=LOGO">
  </div>

  <div class="nav-right">
    <a href="">Responses</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```